# cache not getting cleared?

Tags: caching, drupal-7, memcached

In my content type I have a field (field_fbunique) whose default value is 0; programatically, I change its value to 1 with below code and clear cache.

The value is changed to 1, but when admin users edit the node, the field value is displayed as 0, even though the value in the database is 1 (as expected).

However, to display it as 1, I need to clear cache manually. I have Memcached enabled.

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$node->field_fbunique['und'][0]['value'] = 1;
field_attach_presave('node', $node);
field_attach_update('node', $node);
$nodeurl = url('node/'. $nid); 
cache_clear_all($nodeurl, 'cache_page');
entity_get_controller('node')->resetCache(array($nid));
drupal_flush_all_caches();
```

Answer (score 0):

With help of this code to exclude `form_cache` from `memcache_bins` it started working for me:

```
$conf['memcache_bins'] = array( 'cache' => 'default',  'cache_form' => 'none', );
```